# Determining the geometry parameters of a running terminal

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Window size in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27894/get-window-size-in-shell)

I have a terminal running on the desktop and I would like to determine it's size and coordinates.

I'd like to get the parameters in the format required for  `gnome-terminal --geometry`

Is there any file or variable that holds the geometry parameters of a running terminal?

Thanks

Comment: possible.  does he want size in pixels or characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmctrl -lG`

`xprop -spy`

Also see fred.bear's answer in [Get Window size in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27894/get-window-size-in-shell/27980#27980) .

More info is available in [How to programatically manipulate application windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22568/how-to-programatically-manipulate-application-windows) .